# SQLAlchemy with Flask blueprints: circular imports

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I've got two models, `Company` and `Employee`, in a many-to-one relationship. They are defined in different Flask blueprints. I'm trying to add a cascade, which makes me need to define a relationship on `Company` (instead of just a relationship on `Employee` with `backref` set).

company_blueprint/models.py:

```
class Company(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    employees = relationship("Employee", back_populates="company", cascade="all")
```

employee_blueprint/models.py:

```
from app.company_blueprint.models import Company
class Employee(Base):
    name = Column(String)
    company_id = Column(ForeignKey(Company.id))
    company = relationship("company", back_populates="employees")
```

The problem is, when I try to delete a company in `company_blueprint/views.py`, the `Employee` model is not loaded. I get:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper Mapper|Company|company, expression 'Employee' failed to locate a name ("name 'Employee' is not defined"). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'app.company_model.models.Company'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.
```

I could try to import Employee in `company_blueprint.models`, but then I'm running into a circular import problem.

How do I fix this?

**Edit**: Thanks to Paradoxis, for now I've settled on the following:

- Using strings to refer to foreign key columns, e.g. `company_id = Column(ForeignKey("company.id"))`
- In my `app.py`, first import all models *before* anything else, i.e.

-

```
import flask
import app.employee_blueprint.models
import app.company_blueprint.models

# import other views, modules, etc.
```

This still feels a bit awkward.

Comment: Use your table name as a string as your `ForeignKey("Company.id")` argument and use the class name as a string in your relationship `relationship("Company", ..`

Comment: @Paradoxis This helps so that I can move the import from employee_blueprint/models.py to company_blueprint/models.py, but then I run into the problem from the other side (employee_blueprint/views.py might not know about Company).

Comment: move all of your models into a seperate package, import them all inside the __init__.py and then import them from there in your views, works for me :)

Comment: I just did something similar (without moving them all into one package), which indeed works. Thanks!

Comment: Kindly mark the best answer

Answer (score 0):

I am using such relationships in most of the model classes. According to my understanding, you don't need any special thing or relationship in both classes. Simply add a relationship in parent model class and add a `backref`, it will work.

```
class Company(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    employees = relationship("Employee", backref="company", cascade="all, delete-orphan")
```